# react-boilerplate saving local state

Tags: react-redux, react-boilerplate

using https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate v3.4.0  I want to have elements of the state persisted when the user clicks the refresh button.
What i have done:
in app.js  i changed 
`const initialState = {};
const store = configureStore(initialState, browserHistory);`

to:

```
const initialState = loadState();
const store = configureStore(initialState, browserHistory);
```

where persist.js is used to persist state.global:

```js
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
     const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
     if (serializedState === null) {
       return undefined;
     }
     return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

export const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
     const serializedState = JSON.stringify({ global: state.get('global').toJS()});
     localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
  }
};
```

in the default store.js before store is returned I added:

```
  store.subscribe(() => {
    saveState(store.getState());
  });
```

Obviously this can be improved with throttling later.

So what is happening is after I have authenticated the state is persisting to local storage correctly and it is being reloaded from local storage correctly.

When I refresh the page after authentication, i started tracing store.js:

Before the createStore is run the initialstate is:
[image]

after running:

```js
  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    fromJS(initialState),
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers)
 );
```

the store.getState() returns:

[image]

So what it has done is taken the values from the initial state of the reducers.  I dont understand why this is happening as the redux documentation states:

> You may optionally specify the initial state as the second argument to createStore(). This is useful for hydrating the state of the client to match the state of a Redux application running on the server.

So my question is, how can i get the state persisted after screen refreshes, and why is the initial state being overwritten by the reducers?

Answer (score 0):

turns out there was a typo in one of my reducers - was returning the initialstate not the state for the default action.